# how to open other file manager apps via intent?

Tags: android, file

in my app i use the code below to open up the downloads and only see PDF files. But it opens up the default Android file manager and for other parts of my app to work i need to use other file managers (i am using ES File Manager) to open up instead.

> How do i open up other file manager apps?

(giving the user an option to choose from multiple file manager apps helps too)

My code as of now:

```
public void PDF() {
    PDF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FindPDFBtn);//Finds the button in design and put it into a button variable.
    PDF.setOnClickListener(//Listens for a button click.
            new View.OnClickListener() {//Creates a new click listener.
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {//does what ever code is in here when the button is clicked

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("application/pdf");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a PDF "), SELECT_PDF);

                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with third party file explorers is that most of them don't support the same kind of intents (as they are not standardized).

For ES File explorer, check this: http://www.estrongs.com/res/develop_en.htm